# Can I delete FIRAuth users using their User UID?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have create user used as Admin in firebase auth. Now I want to login and use Admin account to delete other account by using their FIRAuth User UID. How to implement in swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client-side SDKs for Firebase can only delete the currently authenticated user. They do not allow deleting any other user, or deleting a user identified by their UID.

This means that you cannot implement administrative functionality like deleting an arbitrary user in Swift.

Instead you will have to [use the Firebase Admin SDK to delete an arbitrary user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) or [allow your iOS users to delete their own account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#delete_a_user). Given the actions the Admin SDK allows its user to perform, it should only be used in trusted environments, such as a server you control or Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D

Answer (score 2):

You can remove/delete user like this:

**Note:** Some security-sensitive actions—such as **deleting an account**, setting a primary email address, and changing a password—require that the user has recently signed in.

```
 let credential: AuthCredential

            user.reauthenticate(with:credential) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    // An error happened.
                    showAlertWithErrorMessage(message: error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    // User re-authenticated.
                    user.delete { error in
                        if let error = error {
                            // An error happened.
                            showAlertWithErrorMessage(message: error.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            // Account deleted.
                            Database.database().reference(fromURL: kFirebaseLink).child(kUser).child(userID).removeValue()

                            try!  Auth.auth().signOut()
                            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }else{
            showAlertWithErrorMessage(message: "Try again later")
        }
```

This way achieve delete user functionality in my ios app.(remove user from firebase authentication and database both side)

**100% working and tested**

Comment: I would edit your code to show that the `AuthCredential` needs to be initialized first; it's not apparent how it's used to someone unfamiliar with the API.