# Swift4: Delete user accounts from Firebase authentication system

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I would like to be able to remove user accounts from Firebase programmatically by uid, but I only can remove it from database.

Is possible to get something like this on **swift4**?:

```
Task<Void> task = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().deleteUser(uid)
    .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> System.out.println("Successfully deleted user."))
    .addOnFailureListener(e -> System.err.println("Error updating user: " + e.getMessage()));
```

Answer (score 16):

So according [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42859869/7245977)

> The client-side SDKs for Firebase can only delete the currently authenticated user. They do not allow deleting any other user, or deleting a user identified by their UID.

You can [delete a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#delete_a_user) that is currently signed like this:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

user?.delete { error in
  if let error = error {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // Account deleted.
  }
}
```

If you want to delete a user by their UID you'll need to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/)

You can [delete a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) using the Firebase Admin SDK like this:

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Successfully deleted user");
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
  });
```

My advice if you want to delete a user by UID is to perform the following actions.

1. Write the UID of the user you want to delete to a specific area of your database.
2. Use a [real-time database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) to run a cloud function that uses the code above to remove the user account associated with that UID.

Comment: Hi DoesData, I was trying it, but it seems that due to security issues, is not possible to allow the current user to remove another user account.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I said in my answer. That's why you have to use the Admin SDK if you want to do that.

Comment: Can you add the Admin SDK on Swift? I haven't found a pod for it @DoesData

Comment: That would be the client side API so no it doesn't exist in Swift. You can write to your database to trigger a cloud function that can use the admin SDK to delete any user though.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete user from firebase authentication db by simply calling delete on FirebaseUser object.

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
user.delete();
```

But if user is not authenticated recently, it may ask for re-authentication.

Comment: Thanks Arnav, but I would like to have it working on swift.